# Function with b as an unknown real number

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Here is a function $f(x)=x^{\frac{1}{3}}+bx^{\frac{4}{3}}$, notice that $b$ is a real number, where $b \neq0$. How do I

- find the value b where $f(x)$ will have a local minimum?
- Plus that, if $b>0$, how do I find intervals of increase and decrease and concavity?

First, I know $f'(x)=\frac{1}{3}x^{\frac{-2}{3}}+4\frac{b}{3}x^{\frac{1}{3}}$. Then I find $x=0$,$x=\frac{-1}{4b}$ for the critical point. But how can find b where $f(x)$ have local minimum? All I know is when $b>0, x\in(-\infty, 0)$ and when $b<0, x\in (0, \infty)$ for the $\frac{-1}{4b}$. What is done next? Should I analyze $b<0$ and $b>0$ both?

To find concavity, I know $f"(x)=\frac{-2}{9}x^{\frac{-5}{3}}+\frac{4b}{9}x^{\frac{-2}{3}}$. So if b>0, what can I do?

Comment: Hint:You have already solved it, just don't stop and proceed, it will be good to go.

Comment: Take care : $0$ is not a critical point.

Comment: Thank you for comments. But I think 0 is a critical point?